# How to update SQL Table structure from Entity Framework Model

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

I am new to Entity Framework. I have created an EF Model and successfully added some tables and relation. Then I Clicked `Generate Database from Model` and My DB has been updated. Then I renamed some columns and I don't know how to revert or apply the changes. And `Update Model from database` does not seems to work because the columns names are different yet.

I need to graphically sync DB with Model. I prefer the model data rather than db data.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might want to look into the Code-First approach of Entity Framework. Using that approach you'll define your model in your code, and when changing anything you can create a `Migration` which allows you to up- and down-grade the DB to a specific version from the package manager console (or just create the respective SQL scripts).

For more information on this subject please see [this article on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj193542.aspx)

Note that you can also reverse engineer the code first model from an existing database (see `3. Reverse Engineer Model` in [this MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj200620)), and then enable migrations for that model (see `Step 2: Enable Migrations` in [this MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj200620))

Comment: Thank you very much. I can't up vote because of my low reputation.

Answer (score 0):

What I do when I make "updates" is do it on both sides manually, in db and then in model (by right click properties) if the change is small. If adding a "new" table I drag it over to model from db server connections panel.

The alternative I've seen others prefer to use in this cases is to stay away from Entity Framework and use Dapper where you pass queries to it and it handles the rest.

[Dapper (Wins!) vs Entity Framework vs ADO.NET Performance Benchmarking](https://www.exceptionnotfound.net/dapper-vs-entity-framework-vs-ado-net-performance-benchmarking/)